# Single word metaphor for "small and fast"?

Tags: single-word-requests, metaphors

I'm looking for a single word which means "small and fast" - if not literally then metaphorically. I want to use it to describe a piece of software.

As an example, [Midori](http://midori-browser.org/) is "a lightweight, fast [...] web browser". I would like to say something like:

> Compared to Internet Explorer, Midori is [a] ...

Comment: [*Nimble*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/nimble) comes to mind, although is doesn't mean "small".

Comment: Midori is an exocet?

Comment: I propose *agile* and second *nimble*.

Comment: Midori is *scrappy*! (I'm a Midori user/love... except when it crashes)

Comment: Compared to Midori, Internet Explorer is *lumbering* (heavy and slow). Antonyms are agile and nimble (as mentioned) and *light-footed*, though I   doubt you could describe a browser as light-footed!

Comment: @jera Unfortunately, agile is the name of a [development methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development), so it might be a confusing word to use. Most of the time, you'd just say [quick and lightweight](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22quick+and+lightweight%22).

Comment: Speedy Gonzalez?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't commonly defined as meaning *small*, but **zippy** collocates with **little** to such an extent that I think it at least implies smallness.

A [Google Ingram search of *zippy* followed by a wildcard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=zippy%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Czippy%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bzippy%20and%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20little%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20as%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20new%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20dialogue%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20flavor%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20red%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20enough%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bzippy%20performance%3B%2Cc0) shows just how regularly the two words are paired:

[image: Google Ingram of zippy plus wildcard]

A common example appears in the word's definition from MacMillan Dictionaries:

> **zippy**
>   ADJECTIVE INFORMAL
>   able to move very quickly
>   *a zippy little car*

Several other online Dictionaries have a *zippy car* in one of their example sentences. Tellingly, an image search of *zippy car* shows almost exclusively small cars:

[image: Google image search for zippy car]

I also think that the word's association with vehicles that *zip* in and out of traffic also lends the word a connotation of maneuverability.

So if I saw the sentence

> Compared to Microsoft Explorer, Midori is **zippy**.

I would take it to mean that Midori was faster and more responsive, probably due to being less of a behemoth than IE.

---

Just noticed that @Chris H has suggested *nippy* while I was composing this, which sounds like it may be a similar term in the UK (I am in the US).

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you could use 'ferret':

> Compared to [the lumbering, clumsy] Internet Explorer, Midori is a *ferret* of a browser.

Ferrets being small, fast animals that punch considerably above their weight. Naturally, *another* figurative sense of 'ferret' is helpful in this context:

> To uncover and bring to light by searching.
>
> [ferret. (n.d.) American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. (2011). Retrieved November 5 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ferret.]

Not knowing the audience, and sticking to the animal kingdom, I'm avoiding anything the least bit literary, such as

> Compared to [the elephantine] Internet Explorer, Midori is a *serpentine* browser.

'Elephantine' means 'like an elephant', and 'serpentine' means 'like a serpent'.

Similarly, I'm avoiding the touch of cliche involved with bringing the realm of natural phenomena to bear:

> Compared to [the glacial] Internet Explorer, Midori is a *lightning strike* browser.

Answer (score 0):

This may be rare outside the UK. A small car, good at accelerating into rush-hour gaps, and which can corner quite quickly, is often described as *nippy*. It is used for other things as well.  A high sustained speed (on the open road) isn't implied. It has similarities with *responsive*, but of course that has a different meaning in software.